# Windows Onload Causing Script to Stop Working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

When I implemented it it my other script stopped working in IE (FF and others work fine)

Why and what should I do to fix this? I am using jQuery if there is a better way to do the above script and eliminate the issue.

Comment: If you are using jQuery then you shouldn't be using window.onload but jQuery.ready instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using jQuery already, please do it like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    });
```

or

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("loading").style.display = "none";
    });
```

and be aware adding this at the bottom of your HMTL file.

Comment: @Lynda the even terser way of saying `$(document).ready(function(){});` is `$(funcion(){});`

Answer (score 0):

window load and document ready are 2 different events...
You are likely to overwrite your previous onload functionality with your code above.

```
$(window).load=function(){...}
```

should work fine, or you can add to your existing load with something like

```
var oldOnLoad = window.onload; 
window.load= function(){ oldOnLoad; yourNewFunction();}
```